# When I include a .txt file, where does it display a '1' after the content?

Tags: php

I am displaying the contents of a .txt file and the contents display fine by at the end of the content of the file there is a number '1' just randomly. Can anyone tell me why?
Here is what is happening: http://www.baboonhut.com/resources/

The Code:

```
<?php
$dir = 'resources/';

foreach(glob($dir.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $resdir) {
    $resdir = str_replace($dir, '', $resdir);
    echo "
<div class=\"span3\">
<div class=\"tile\">
<img src=\"resources/". $resdir ."/thumbnail.png\" class=\"img-rounded\">
<h3 class=\"tile-title\">". $resdir ."</h3>
<p>"; echo  include('resources/'. $resdir .'/description.txt'); echo "</p>
<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block\" href=\"http://www.baboonhut.com/resources/" . $resdir ."/\">More Information</a>
</div>
</div>
"
;
}
?>
```

Comment: Because `include` returns either `1` or `false`. You are `echo`ing the return value of that statement. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php: *"Handling Returns: `include` returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing that, you should do `readfile`, it will output the text just like you were expecting.

```
readfile('resources/'. $resdir .'/description.txt');
```

In my opinion, `include` is made for including php files that need to execute something, not for displaying data of a text file.

Answer (score 2):

Its showing `1` because of this line

```
echo  include('resources/'. $resdir .'/description.txt');
 ^
 |--- Remove this
```

But if you want to use `echo` then

```
echo file_get_contents('resources/' . $resdir . '/description.txt');
```

Or

```
readfile('resources/' . $resdir . '/description.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing out your include you should just include it:

`include('resources/'. $resdir .'/description.txt');`

Include returns true, which evaluates to 1, which is what you are seeing in your output.